# How can I force text to ignore other elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a project that hides and shows elements using the visibility parameter. Another element is pushing the text in these elements down and I need to know if there is a way to force the text back to the top of its element. I have tried different display parameters, floats, etc and haven't found anything (other than absolute position) that will work. The problem with absolute positioning is that the container div will then hide overflow instead of expanding with the content. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TL969/)

```
check JSFiddle for example and code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is the relative position of the list:

```css
#list {
    position: relative;
    left: -25%;
}
```

If you switch to using `margin-left` instead of `left`, you get the layout you want:

```css
#list {
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TL969/2/

With relative positioning, surrounding elements are not affected by adjustments.  Surrounding elements are layed out as though no adjustments were made to the positioning.  By positioning it with negative margin instead, surrounding elements are affected, and thus you free up room for the text.